# Using Linux commands on files across multiple servers

Tags: linux, dns, hostname

I am new to Linux as a whole and so far I have not found a solution to this that isnt clumsy at best. I have a Windows background and so I am accustomed to running commands on one server that access text files on multiple systems in the same domain.

Example of what is processed in Windows:

```
find "Some text" \\ServerName01\c$\inetpub\*.log
find "Some text" \\ServerName02\c$\inetpub\*.log
find "Some text" \\ServerName03\c$\inetpub\*.log
```

Example of what I would LIKE to do in Linux:

```
sed 's/SomeText/OtherText/p //ServerName01/var/opt/somefolder/*.log
sed 's/SomeText/OtherText/p //ServerName02/var/opt/somefolder/*.log
sed 's/SomeText/OtherText/p //ServerName03/var/opt/somefolder/*.log
```

What is the best way to do the above in Linux, or is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to answer if you could explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish in english instead of giving an example in Windows command language -- among other things, many Unix experts do not know Windows command language.

Comment: How are you trying to do it, are they local servers or are you trying to do it via ssh? If so it is it a terminal ssh or a gui application like putty or something similar?

Comment: should probably be moved to superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a lot of way for doing it :

- Via NFS/Fuse Mount, mount the logs directory on one system and you could do the same thing as windows (which automatically mount remote filesystem with the "\\")
- use ssh,(that would be my prefered solution)

cat serverlist | xargs -i ssh {} " grep \"some text\" yourfilepaths"

which helps if you use ssh keys pairs

Answer (score 2):

See the pssh and pscp suite, you can run commands on a bunch of remote servers : http://www.theether.org/pssh/

Answer (score 2):

pssh or cssh would work

> pssh provides a number of commands for executing against a group of
>   computers, using SSH. It’s most useful for operating on clusters of
>   homogenously-configured hosts.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/execute-commands-simultaneously-on-multiple-servers-using-psshcluster-sshmultixterm.html